Issue with Encoding.UTF8.GetString and Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes Resulting in Different Array Lengths
I'm encountering a problem. In my encryption function, I have the following lines:
var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted);
var urlEncodedValue = WebUtility.UrlEncode(result);

Here, the encrypted variable is a byte array with a length of 48.
In my decryption function, I have these lines:
var urlDecodedValue = WebUtility.UrlDecode(cryptedHeaderValue);
var urlDecodedProtectedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(urlDecodedValue);

While debugging, the urlDecodedValue and urlEncodedValue appear identical as strings, but urlDecodedProtectedData is a byte array with a length of 87, causing my decryption to fail.
It's important to note that the encryption is done in .NET Framework 4.8, while the decryption is done in a .NET Core 8 project.
Thanks!

You made sure that (by debugging for example) that urlEncodedValue on one side is identical to cryptedHeaderValue on the other side? So nothing happens between those two code examples we don't see? urlEncodedValue and urlDecodedValue  shouldn't be equal as you say. One is encoded the other is not.

This line var result =  Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted); probably makes no sense and corrupts the data. Encrypted data is not the UTF-8 encoding of a character string, and in particular will very likely contain byte sequences that are invalid in UTF-8. The same is true for compressed data and almost every other kind of binary data. If you must convert binary data to a string for some reason you must use an appropriate encoder, like base64.

Agreed, the only safe, standardized way of encoding binary data (including text which has been encrypted) into a URL is to use Base64: var urlEncodedValue =  Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted); and then you don't need to reencode it either.

Uh, better use an URL safe alphabet though if you want to use it in an URL. It's a bit of a downer that it isn't included in the standard libs by default as string substitution is relatively costly w.r.t. memory / performance but as indicated, there are ways around that.

Base32 is always URL safe, but is longer than Base64.
